# In Google account permissions, what does "View basic information about your account" mean?

Tags: security, google-chrome, permissions

Google allows users to manage their [account permissions](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions) but I have been having a hard time figuring out what some of these applications are allowed to do. I have been looking around and can't find exactly what this phrase "View basic information about your account" means. I assume it is something like your name, DOB, image, etc. but can't find where this is all spelled out specifically or precisely.

Other permissions don't seem well explained either like "Know who you are on Google," "Manage your contacts," "Connect to an external service," "View and manage data associated with the application," "Manage your calendars," "Manage the email migration settings on your domain," "Manage your YouTube account," etc.

Is there someplace that explains what all these security phrases mean?